# Cannot resolve shuffle function of a chararray object

Tags: android

I am following a google codelab of android kotlin basics, in the code lab, he calls shuffle function on a char array object as follows

```
val tempWord = currentWord.toCharArray()
tempWord.shuffle()
```

but for me shuffle function is unresolved, why?

Comment: if you are sure you did it correct, it can be a bug you can try build -> clean project then build -> rebuild project and if it does not work you can try file -> Invalidate caches / restart  can you try this three steps?

Comment: Thanks alot but still not working, i'll just pass it i just thought it's an error in configuration or something but it looks like a mistake from google

Comment: but it works for me i used a string and tried this and it worked maybe your type was different.

Comment: The problem was with configuration as i expected, the codelab uses a newer version than mine, after upgrading it works, thanks for helping

Comment: Congratulations.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you were trying to use [`Collections.shuffle`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29)?

It can be used like so

```
    List<Character> chars = Arrays.asList(charArray);

    long seed = System.currentTimeMillis();

    Random rand = new Random(seed);

    Collections.shuffle(chars, rand);

    chars.toArray(charArray);
```

Comment: Yes, i can indeed use it on collections, but the code lab called it on a char array object :/

Comment: Maybe the codelabs made a mistake too and you haven't mentioned any link to any codelab so I felt I should give you a suggestion :)

Comment: I am actually greatful anyway , here is the code https://github.com/google-developer-training/android-basics-kotlin-unscramble-app/tree/starter